# Implemented appstore/integrations in an SaaS application

Tags: web-applications, software-as-a-service, appstore

What is the best way to implement a app store in a SaaS application? For example, say you have an ERP application and you want to allow external accounting systems to integrate into your application.

I was personally thinking about a combination of webhooks (to send the latest info to the external app) and allowed the app to make API calls to update existing data.

I'm not looking for any implementation, just looking for some ideas was I wasn't able to find any usefull info

Answer (score 0):

Well I would start out by saying that there are a million different ways to accomplish what it is that your asking, just like anything else in software, it will depend on what your constraints are.

That being said it seems to me like you arent looking to implement a full blown app store, but are rather looking for more of a standardized extension point which other applications can then write code to consume. Correct me if I am wrong on this assumption! If this is the case, then what I would recommend would be to follow the RESTful design principles and expose an API which your target audience could then consume via any means that can speak HTTP. This grants you the benefit of allowing your API implementation to be completely ignorant of the language by which it is consumed.

If you are going to go this route, one of the downsides is that you will have to define a substantial amount of documentation which will inform your downstream users of what it is that is available for them to call via the API. This task can be almost entriley automated if you are using a framework like ASP.NET Core *(although other frameworks are also supported via the Swagger specification)* with a utility that is publicly available called **[Swagger](https://swagger.io/)** and its counterpart **[Swagger.UI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/)** which can expose a automatically generated user interface accessible via ports 80/443 which gives your consuming developers a full blown exploratory interface!